# AMP: using amp-sidebar CSS attribute

Tags: amp-html

I am using amp side-bar. it has the CSS attribute of "width:80vw;"I would like to expand the width. how can I do that? I have issues with the "important" attribute in the CSS

Comment: Iam afraid that we cannot help you if you do not provide the related HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Amp Sidebar has an id as sidebar. Just change that width and leave max-width as it is. Also by doing so it will not show any error in amp validator.

```
#sidebar {
    width: 500px;
}
```